# CLion and messages

Tags: clion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For CLion users out there:

I'm trying out CLion, and wondering how to deal w/ msgs that are created by the build process. I was able to make CLion happy by hacking up my src/myproj/CMakeLists.txt file:

```
## Set up include directories
include_directories(
  include
  ../../devel/include # Hack for Clion
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

Is there a better way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275684/clion-and-messages/) by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2017-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Clyde,

Did you try to: (1) compile the package containing the new messages, (2) source catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash (3) launch Clion from the terminal where you sourced catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash?

It works on my machine. Maybe have a look at this other post: [link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/210534/jetbrains-clion-ide-setup-for-ros/?answer=210543#post-id-210543)

Cheers,

Marco.

---

Originally posted by [Femer](https://answers.ros.org/users/26134/femer/) with karma: 253 on 2017-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-11-13**:
Ah... I was confused about proj/devel vs. proj/src/cmake-build-devel. I [re-]built the targets using CLion and now it's all happy.

It appears that CLion users to be careful about managing 2 build environments: CLion and catkin.

Thanks!

**Comment by [PSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/37801/psa/) on 2018-09-28**:
For future users, go to proj/src/cmake-build-devel and run "make". This will generate the custom messages and then Clion will pick up on the new included messages.